# flutter local notification on firestore change

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream

In my firestore I have a list of documents which represent locations on a map.

I would like to show a local notification not only when a new document is created in the database, but also when the location is within a certain distance from my current location.

At the moment I have a streambuilder which loads the position into my local map, and a streamlistener to give a notification on a new document:

```
  CollectionReference loc =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('locations');
  late Stream<QuerySnapshot> _locStream;
  late StreamSubscription<QuerySnapshot> streamSub;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _locStream = loc.snapshots();

    streamSub = _locStream.listen((data) {
      final snackBar = SnackBar(
          content:
              Text('New location added!'));

      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);

    });
  }
```

the problem is that the stream is returning ALL the documents, not only the new one, so I have no idea how to "isolate" the new one and, more important, how to get its value in order to compare it with my current location.

Is that possible to achieve so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Firestore `QuerySnapshot` always contains all information that fits within the query. But when the `QuerySnapshot` is an update on an existing listener/stream, it also contains metadata about what changes compared to the previous `QuerySnapshot` on the listener/stream.

To get access to this metadata, use the `QuerySnapshot`'s [`docChanges` property](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot/docChanges.html), rather than `docs`, and check the [`DocumentChangeType`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/latest/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/DocumentChangeType.html) of the `type` property of each change to find only the documents that were added. In the initial snapshot that will be all of the documents, since all of them are new to the snapshot at that point.

See the Firebase documentation on [viewing changes between snapshots](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots)

Comment: it would also be interesting to know how to "isolate" the initial snapshot. Otherwise the snackbar will be displayed for all the documents contained in the snapshot, at each app startup

Comment: There's nothing built in for that. If you only want to show notifications for new data, you'll want to query for only new data. For example, if "new" for you means that it was after a certain date/time, include a timestamp in each document, and use a query to retrieve only documents are that date/time.

Comment: ok clear. I thought there was something already out of the box :) thanks Frank